# Hide Bottom Option Bar in Android

Tags: android

I want to hide Bottom Option Bar in Android. I don't know whether we call it Option Bar it or not.
Please check it out Image below : Tell me if we call it something else. It is in bottom. 
Now, I want to hide it. How to do it ?
[image: Hide Option Bar]

Comment: Are you talk in about Navigation bar?

Comment: @SimplePlan, Sry, As I have said clearly in post, I dint know its exact name

Comment: Go to official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) for better understanding of Navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

It's called navigation bar, the reason for it only having the *options* button is probably because your device has hardware buttons for home and back, that's why it looks like an options button only bar.

[Refer to the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) for hiding it, although it will only work for versions supporting it.
For 4.0+

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```